# Sort Key/Pair based on a calculation

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary

I have `KeyValuePair` in which the `value` contains a Generic List of one of my class.

so for each value I calculate one column and based on that value I display it in table format.

But here my problem is: for each List of Values it contains one row with `0` as a column value which I get by calculation.

so I want that value to be on a top place. but right now it can be at any place.

So how can I sort that based on that calculation.?

Here is my code:

```
 @foreach (KeyValuePair<String, List<MyClass>> keyValuePair in aClient.ESelectionDictionary)
{
    foreach (MyClass eData in keyValuePair.Value)
    {
        string weight;
        ............
        //Here comes some calculations
        ............
        if (weight == 0d)
        {
            addclass = "class=hidden";
        }
        else
        {
            addclass = "class=main";
        }
    }
}
```

so here for all values in `eData`, `weight` is always `0d` except one value.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: "for each value I calculate one column" - what column do you mean?

Comment: We need to sort based on the calculation judging by your post, so could you please post the calculation?

Comment: One suggestion not a answer, Use `Dictionary` instead of List of `KeyValuePair`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new dictionary based on the previous one with the list ordered by your custom function to calculate column index:

```
var reshuffled = aClient.ESelectionDictionary.ToDictionary(
   kvp => kvp.Key,
   kvp => kvp.Value.OrderBy(CalculateColumnIndex)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add intermediate collection where you will have the items in the desired order and implement two loops, first will populate the collection in the order you are looking for, second loop will render the table:

```
var list = new List<MyClass>(keyValuePair.Value.Count);

foreach (MyClass eData in keyValuePair.Value)
{
    string weight;
    ............
    //Here comes some calculations
    ............
    if (weight == 0d)
    {
        list.Insert(0, eData);
    }
    else
    {
        list.Add(eData);
    }
}

foreach (var eData in list)
    // render eData into table
```